# LLVM-3.1 libLLVMSupport.a undefined reference to `dladdr'

Tags: compiling

I'm trying to compile using the llvm-3.1 package.
I'm running 12.04 x64 (3.2.0-26 kernel) && 12.10 (3.5.0-4) x64  backported llvm-3.1 from quantal, then debian experimental.
Next I tried 12.10 with the native ubuntu llvm-3.1 package; this failed as well.

```
user@system:/tmp/llvm-test# make  
compiling cpp yacc file: decaf-llvm.y  
output file: decaf-llvm  
bison -b decaf-llvm -d decaf-llvm.y  
/bin/mv -f decaf-llvm.tab.c decaf-llvm.tab.cc  
flex -odecaf-llvm.lex.cc decaf-llvm.lex  
g++ -o ./decaf-llvm decaf-llvm.tab.cc decaf-llvm.lex.cc decaf-stdlib.c `llvm-config --cppflags --ldflags --libs core jit native` -ly -ll  
/usr/lib/llvm-3.1/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Signals.o): In function `PrintStackTrace(void*)':
(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to `dladdr'  
/usr/lib/llvm-3.1/lib/libLLVMSupport.a(Signals.o): In function `PrintStackTrace(void*)':
(.text+0x18f): undefined reference to `dladdr'  
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status  
make: *** [decaf-llvm] Error 1
```

I know the code works as I've run it in centos fine using `llvm-3.1-6.fc18(rpm)`

Google was a bit helpful with this:

> "On some systems, incluning Ubuntu 11.10, linking may fail with message 
> that libLLVMSupport.a in function PrintStackTrace(void*) has undefined 
> reference to dladdr."

> "Workaround is to compile LLVM with cmake specifying the following
>   variable:
>   -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS=-ldl"

http://svn.dsource.org/projects/bindings/trunk/llvm-3.0/Readme

I double checked y ldflags and everything seems ok.

```
user@system:/llvm-config --ldflags
-L/usr/lib/llvm-3.1/lib  -lpthread -lffi -ldl -lm
```

I'm unclear of what to do next; any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I asked (and answered) a similar question [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993460/why-am-i-getting-undefined-reference-to-dladdr-even-with-ldl-for-this-simpl). Adapting my answer from that question to yours:

The library requiring the symbols is included by `-lLLVMSupport`, so `-ldl` must come after `-lLLVMSupport`. See [Why does the order of '-l' option in gcc matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893996/why-does-the-order-of-l-option-in-gcc-matter) on Stack Overflow. You need to change this:

```
`llvm-config --cppflags --ldflags --libs core jit native`
```

To this:

```
`llvm-config --cppflags --libs core jit native` `llvm-config --ldflags`
```

And the linker should be successful. Let me know if you find a better solution to fix the order of `--ldflags`.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-xcb-dev llvm-dev x11proto-gl-dev x11proto-dri2-dev libxext-dev libxdamage-dev libxfixes-dev libxcb-glx0 libxcb-glx0-dev libpng12-dev
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This answer would benefit substantially, if you were to edit it to add some explanation (or at least to tell the user exactly *what to do* with these lines).